# Spring MVC + AngularJs: JSON/Model values set to null

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying submit json data to a Spring MVC controller mapped with a model. Instead of getting the json values, the values of the fields of the model are all NULL.

IDE debugger:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public PostResponse update(Setting setting, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        return settingService.processUpdate(setting, bindingResult, messageSource);
    }
```

JSON data:

```
{  
   "updatedAt":1460600207000,
   "id":1,
   "createdBy":null,
   "description":"This is a setting",
   "code":"MY_SETTING",
   "value":"{\"id\":\"1018\",\"title\":\"Another setting\",\"code\":\"220-203-10-101\"}"
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Setting {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private String value;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date updatedAt;

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_createdByUserId")
    private User createdBy;

    public Setting() {}

    public Setting(String code, String description, String value, Date createdAt, Date updatedAt, User createdBy) {
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public User getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(User createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
```

Comment: update your data on generated id `@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)` and pass your id in `@PathVariable` so data you can update your data for particular id

Comment: The the values of the fields of the model are all NULL. Even if I have the id, updating would be useless. @RequestBody did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the setting bean is not mapped at all.

You need to tell spring how to map the http request to the method arguments. If you're posting data, the best way is to add `@RequestBody` annotation to the relevant method argument (`setting` in your case)

Modify your controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public PostResponse update(@RequestBody Setting setting, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        return settingService.processUpdate(setting, bindingResult, messageSource);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot @RequestBody :)